# How to get all the values of the checked and unchecked checkbox array and save it to database in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I'm having trouble in getting the values of the checked and unchecked checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, it will get the value of that particular checkbox and whenever the checkbox is unchecked, the  value of the unchecked checkbox will be 0.

This is my html code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
        <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 40px;">
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="5"> Barangay business permit </td>
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="10"> Business plate </td>
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="20"> Sanitary inspection fee </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 40px;">
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="30"> Environmental clearance </td>
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="40"> Barangay development </td>
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="50"> building permit </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 40px;">
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="60"> Electrical inspection </td>
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="70"> Mechanical inspection    </td>
            <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="80"> Plumbing inspection </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<div class="" style="margin: auto; padding-top:20px;">Total <input type="text" name="total" style="color: #222222;" readonly/>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" style="width: 100px; height:50px; margin:auto; color:#222222;">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];

    for($i=0; $i<count($checkbox); $i++)
    {
        $num[$i]=$checkbox[$i];
    }
```

Javascript codes (for the function of getting the values of each checkbox while checking and generating a total in the total field.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        var applications = [];
        //bind the change event to the checkboxes
        $('input[name="checkbox[]"]').change(function(){
            var total = 0;
            //get value from each selected ckeck box
            $('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').each(function(){
                var tval = $(this).val();
                total += parseFloat(tval);
            });
            //finally display the total with a ₱ sign
            $('input[name="total"]').val("₱ " + total);

            // handle applications
            var application = $.trim($(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue); // get the name
            var i = applications.indexOf(application);
            if(i != -1) {
                applications.splice(i, 1); // remove if unchecked
            } else {
                applications.push(application); // push if checked
            }
            var temp = applications.join(', ');
            $('input[name="applications"]').val(temp);

        });

    });
    </script>
```

In the actual test, I checked some of the checkbox in the table [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]. Note: 1 represents as checked and 0 represents as unchecked to make it clear.

When I click on submit button and display the values, I got this

[0] => 10

[1] => 40

[2] => 50

But I want to get the values like this

[0] => 0

[1] => 10

[2] => 0

[3] => 0

[4] => 40

[5] => 50

[6] => 0

[7] => 0

[8] => 0

How can I get that values? I need to get each value of the unchecked as 0 & checked values then save each array (in order) to database. I really need a help, I searched it from the net but I didn't get the right solution to my problem. I think my php codes is wrong.

database name: application

table: fees

columns: ID, fee1, fee2, fee3, fee4, fee5, fee6, fee7, fee8, fee9

Comment: unchecked are not posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, you can use `array_replace` on this.

First build the default structure thru `array_fill()` (since unchecked checkboxes are not going to be included the POST). Then finally `array_replace` the default with the input. Example:

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rSieZy)

```
<?php

$default = array_fill(0, 9, 0);
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $input = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $final = array_replace($default, $input);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($final);
}

?>
<form method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 40px;">
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]" value="5" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Barangay business permit </td>
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="10" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Business plate </td>
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" value="20" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Sanitary inspection fee </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 40px;">
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" value="30" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Environmental clearance </td>
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[4]" value="40" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Barangay development </td>
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[5]" value="50" class="toggle_checkbox" /> building permit </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 40px;">
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[6]" value="60" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Electrical inspection </td>
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[7]" value="70" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Mechanical inspection    </td>
                <td style="width: 240px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[8]" value="80" class="toggle_checkbox" /> Plumbing inspection </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" style="width: 100px; height:50px; margin:auto; color:#222222;">
    </table>
</form>
```

Sidenote: You need to explicitly put indices on the name attribute so that they are going to be aligned when the replace takes in.

And then in your JS:

Since you cannot use the name calling because of the indices, turn it into `classes` instead:

```
$('.toggle_checkbox').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    //get value from each selected ckeck box
    $('.toggle_checkbox:checked').each(function(){
```

Comment: I edited my question and added the javascript function. I tried your codes but the automatic generation of the total values while checking the checkbox is not working because I think changing the checkbox[] name to checkbox[with numbers] will affect the javascript function.

Comment: @Ejardy just change the `.change` to `$('.toggle_checkbox')` instead of pointing the `name=""`

Comment: @Ejardy i made the revision try again

Comment: sorry for late reply. Your code works! But how can I assign per array in a variable for me to save it to database?

Comment: @Ejardy normally just loop it, under the loop is the insertion query, or you can also build a query such that it will inert multiple rows.

Comment: sa barangay tol! project eh hehe! sorry late reply, nasa work kasi.

Comment: @Ejardy ahh okay bro no prob

Comment: bro are you familiar with the codes of one time download only? Thanks!

Comment: @Ejardy too broad bro, can be done in myriads of ways, maybe add a flag in DB table `is_downloaded`, initial value `0`, after the first download, update to `1`, so that it can never be downloaded again

Comment: but what if the download is cancelled by the user or internet disruptions occurred before the download finishes?

Comment: @Ejardy yeah i thought so too, maybe this could shed some light, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: Maybe I'll go first to the easiest way for deleting the file from the database. I can't fully understand how the codes are working. Thanks for the suggestions! I will just change my download php soon when I learned that codes.

Comment: I have a problem with the radio buttons. Here is the link [RadioButtons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603155/checking-the-correct-answer-from-the-database-by-a-checked-radio-button-in-php/26603425?noredirect=1#comment41838514_26603425). I hope you can help me tol :)

Comment: @Ejardy imo, you could just follow Shaunak's answer, create a table for the answers as well, and use the relationships between that table questions and table answers, `question_id` etc. then during the form, if this is a set of questions (`5 or 10, or whatever`). load each set of question and then save each user selection in a session

Comment: My answers is located inside the table of my question. I don't know exactly what it looks like the code for comparison of the selected radio button to the correct answer in the database. I mean the codes inside the $_POST['finish']; which is the button.

Comment: @Ejardy then just catch the form submission, get all user input. (including which questions have been presented, since its randomized). then compare the selected answer against the correct answer

Comment: I really don't have any idea how to get the values. I'm just a newbie in php and I have to learn a lot of things about php. kain muna ako.

Comment: @Ejardy just access post values like you normally would do `$_POST['radio']` blah blah something like that. most likely this will return an array. the keys of that array are the ids since you explicitly set them inside the markup. `name[radio][<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='hidden' name='checkbox[0]' value='0'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[0]' value='10'/>
```

Because the names are the same, php will overwrite the default value with the checkbox value if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#save").click(function(){
var check = [];
$('.checkBox:checked').each(function() 
{check.push($(this).val());});
var count=check.length;
var data={"Header":"some data","details":[]};
var detail={"values":""};
for(i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
var val=check[i];
detail.values=val;
data.details.push(detail);
detail={"values":""};
}
$.ajax({
url:"data/save",
data:JSON.stringify(data),
success:function(){
alert("sukses !!");
}
});

});
```