# Checking the correct answer from the database by a checked radio button in PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

I am creating an Online Assessment. I display all the questions randomly in a one page only. I have difficulty on how to check the correct answer in the database for checked radio button. I don't know what to do and the logic on how to do it.

This is my php codes for displaying the questions randomly,

```
$view_questions=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND()");
```

This is my html codes with php codes,

```
<form name="" method="POST">
                </br><h4># of Questions</h4>
                <?php
                $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view_questions))
                    {
                ?>
                <div class="view_question fsize">

                    <p align="justify"><?php echo $i;?>) <?php echo $row['QUESTION'];?></p>
                    <div class="indent-question">
                        <input type="radio" value="1" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_1'];?>
                        </br>
                        <input type="radio" value="2" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_2'];?>
                        </br>
                        <input type="radio" value="3" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_3'];?>
                        </br>
                        <input type="radio" value="4" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_4'];?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $i++;
                    }
                ?>
                <center><button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' name="finish" type='submit'>Finish</button></center>
            </form>
```

Table name: questions

Table fields: QUESTION_NO, QUESTION, ANSWER_1, ANSWER_2, ANSWER_3, ANSWER_4, ANSWER

Comment: Store your answers as an INT in the database. Then you just just compare the value from your radiobutton to the value in the database.

Comment: Use ajax and comparison technique to sort out the selected answer is right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy

store Id of you questions in the value in the radio button and checkbox only those value are submitted which are checked , compare your code after submitting the form in next page , I hope you will understand, What i am trying to say

Comment: There is no next page for my Assessment because I displayed all my questions in a one page. The Finish button will check all the answered radio buttons to the correct answer in the database.

Comment: then where are you submitting your values ?

Comment: @Sohail Here is the process, first I displayed the questions and answers (multiple choice) in a one page. Then the user will answer the questions by checking the radio button each question. When the user is finished, the user will now click the finish button. My problem is that I don't know how to check each checked radio buttons if the answer of the user is matched with the correct answer in the database.

Comment: You dont need check each question , You only need to check what user has checked, match the value which is checked , if this matches with the database correct answer ,then  Mark this true , if not then false what ever your logic is for the true or the false

Answer (score 0):

You should have database structure like this..

```
Table 1: Questions
Fields: que_id, question

Table 2: Answers
Fields: ans_id, que_id, answer, correct_ans, points

Table 3: Results
Fields: que_id, ans_id
```

When you add question, question and que_id will be stored n database.. Then you'll add multiple possible answers which are stored in Answers table with reference to que_id..

You need to change query for GUI to fetch question and answer from different table using join.
So GUI would be like this..

```
<form name="" method="POST">
                </br><h4># of Questions</h4>
                <?php
                $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view_questions))
                    {
                ?>
                <div class="view_question fsize">

                    <p align="justify"><?php echo $i;?>) <?php echo $row['QUESTION'];?></p>
                    <div class="indent-question">
                        <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['ans_id']; ?>" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_1'];?>
                        </br>
                        <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['ans_id']; ?>" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_2'];?>
                        </br>
                        <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['ans_id']; ?>" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_3'];?>
                        </br>
                        <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['ans_id']; ?>" id="" name="radio[<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>]"> <?php echo $row['ANSWER_4'];?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $i++;
                    }
                ?>
                <center><button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' name="finish" type='submit'>Finish</button></center>
            </form>
```

After that when user select an answer, ans_id will be saved along with the que_id in results table, from there you can manage all the information and comparison..

Comment: Can I have a sample codes for processing the information and comparison for the selected radio buttons after I click the finish button? I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

set Answerquestions to value for radio button

```
<input type="radio" value="ANSWER1" name="name">
<input type="radio" value="ANSWER2" name="name">
```

in php code 
check the value submited with the correct Answer

get the correct Answer from db and save it in var

```
$query "SELECT correct_answer FROM TABEL_NAME";
```

and fetch query in var correct_a for example

```
$user_answer = $_POST['name'];
if($user_answer == $correct_a)
   return true 
else
   return false
```

Comment: Maybe this codes is for questions one by one per page. In my scenario, I displayed all the questions in a one page and the problem is that I don't know how to check the checked radio buttons to the correct answer in the database.

Comment: ok make value for radio like this
`<input type="radio" value="questionID-ANSWER1" name="name">`
questionID its question_ID in your database .
in php code split the value like this 
`$value = $_POST['name'];
$result = explode('-', $value);
`

here we have an array 
`$result[0]; // value is question_ID
$result[1];// value is ANSWER`
here you can comparison between question_ID in radio button and question_ID in your db If equaled then comparison user Answer with correct Answer in db if equaled return true else return false