# How to also include unselected checkboxes in the array along with the selected boxes using an implode statement?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I include both selected and unselected boxes along with the checked and unchecked respective attributes?

```
$input_item = "".((isset($_POST["item"]))?implode(", ",$_POST["item"]):"")."";
$selectedCheckboxes = explode(', ', $input_item);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "<p>
      <input type='checkbox' name='item[]' value='".$row['item']."' id='item_0'".(in_array($row['item'], $selectedCheckboxes)?'checked':'')."> ".$row['item']."</p>
    ";

   
}
```

Comment: @Scuzzy, the question is not clear. Both checked and unckecked checkboxes should be drawn with this code. Try to describe what you want to get in the end.

Comment: @7-zete-7 your solution works in storing the checkboxes. But, I also want to store the unchecked values. So, I can later pull and display them on the update page.

Comment: @7-zete-7 as, the checkbox values are dynamic. They change based on certain criteria. Therefore, I want to store both. So, the respective values can be easily be retrieved while performing update. Hope that makes sense. fyi: I solved the other issue regarding the update page. It was not updating bcz the id variable was before the allowance variable. rearranging solved the issue.

Comment: Checkboxes either exist in the submission data because they are checked, or they don't exist in the submission payload because they weren't checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is necessary to change the structure of the stored data. from an enumeration like `"1, 2, 3"` it is impossible to understand which value is checked and which is unchecked.

For example use JSON and storing data as like `["1":"1","2":"0","3":"1"]`:

```php
$input_item = isset($_POST['item']) ? json_encode($_POST['item']) : '';
$selectedCheckboxes = json_decode($input_item, true);

$idx = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $itemName = $row['item'];
  $isChecked = isset($selectedCheckboxes[$itemName]) && $selectedCheckboxes[$itemName];

  echo "<p>
      <input type='hidden' name='item[{$itemName}]' value='0'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='item[{$itemName}]' value='1' ".($isChecked ? 'checked' : '')."> ".$itemName."</p>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working to some extent. The only issue I am having is that it is adding check attribute to the uncheck values as well. So, when I pull the values. they all have a tick in the checkbox even the unchecked ones.

Comment: `isset($selectedCheckboxes[$itemName]) && $selectedCheckboxes[$itemName]` can be simplified to `!empty($selectedCheckboxes[$itemName])`

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` can be functionless: `foreach ($result as $row) {`.

Comment: Exact duplicate advice from 7 years ago.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25987030/2943403  Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.

Comment: @mickmackusa, please read the question carefully. The questioner has not only a question from the answer you suggested, but also a question about the data storage structure.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I agree, the code can be simplified or made more beautiful. But will the questioner understand it after such modifications? In the answer, I leave its code, adding the required actions in it.